# Is this generalization of Carnot's theorem known?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, conic-sections

This morning I found that [Carnot's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(conics)) for the conic transversal of a triangle can be generalized to any polygon, and the generalization can be proven by applying mathematical induction to Carnot's theorem itself. For example, when applying the generalization to a quadrilateral, the equation becomes as shown in the image below.

[image]
Is this generalization known?

Thank you

Comment: See #3 at http://users.math.uoc.gr/~pamfilos/eGallery/problems/CarnotConics.html